# Different datatype implementation on each cell for UI Grid

Tags: javascript, spreadsheet, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid, jexcelapi

I am using UI Grid for my spreadsheet implementation.
My grid consists of complex big data.
How do i access individual cell/cells in the table to assign them datatypes .

[My grid example is as follows:][1]

```
  [1]: http://plnkr.co/edit/3YskfpKIe4UFjpTAIh5o?p=preview
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like most of your example fields would be strings. To add types you would add the `type` to the columnDefs. A list of acceptable types can be found here in the "types" section. 
[ColumnDef Documentation](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/api/ui.grid.class:GridOptions.columnDef)

```
  columnDefs: 
  [
    { name:'firstName', field: 'first-name', type: 'string' },
    { name:'1stFriend', field: 'friends[0]', type: 'string' },
    { name:'city', field: 'address.city', type: 'string' },
    { name:'getZip', field: 'getZip()', enableCellEdit: false, type: 'string' }
  ]
```

EDIT: I see your questions ask specifically how to do this on a cell. I don't know why you would want to do this usually all cells of a column share a type.